# Special case of nonsymmetric algebraic Riccati equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I have a variant of nonsymmetric algebraic Riccati equation where $D = 0$: $XAX + BX + C = 0$. All matrices are real. Additionally, $C$ is dioganal and all elements of $A$ are nonnegative.

1. There exists an analytical solution of this form of the equation?
2. There exist additional constraints on $A, B, C$ such that an analytical solution exists?

Comment: Do you consider that $A,B,C,X$ are real ? On the other hand, $X$ should be analytic wrt. what? ($A,B,C$ are fixed).

Comment: @loupblanc Yes, all matrices are real. I add this in my question.

Comment: What is the answer to my second question? Where are the variables? Do you want a formula as in the case when $n=1$?  I think that I spend my time...